# How can I make git log include the timestamp, username, action, and file name on a single line?

Tags: git

I want to get a CSV dump of history from git that looks something like this:

```
1344882131,Josh Yeager,A,main.cs
1344882131,Josh Yeager,A,other.cs
1344882191,John Doe,D,other.cs
```

The first column is the UNIX timestamp, the second is the author name, the third is the action (A/M/D), and the last is the file name. I figured out how to get the timestamp and author name for every commit, but I can't figure out how to make it also list the files in the commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give `--name-status` as an argument to `git log`, it will include the filenames and actions, and you're just left with a bit of text processing to join the commit and action data together and produce the CSV output.

Comment: That gave me the output below, which spreads the data across several lines. I'm trying to get it on one line.

`$ git log --name-status
commit 61a287c3705cdd02616334b0dee7480faee7e9c8
Author: Josh Yeager
Date:   Wed Sep 5 11:15:32 2012 -0400

    Task Id: 101655 - comments redacted

M       Logic/JobSave.cs`

Comment: You can use the `--pretty=format:...` argument to format the commit information onto one line, and then post-process the output to join up and repeat the commit information for each file action.